# type_name_not_found - (Javers , Spring-boot)

Tags: javers

Using `javers-core 3.10.2` and `javers-spring-boot-starter-sql 3.10.2` javers works well initially. But after restarting **spring boot** application getting following error.

> JaversException **TYPE_NAME_NOT_FOUND:** type name 'Person' not found. If you are using @TypeName annotation, remember to register this class using JaversBuilder.withPackagesToScan(String) or JaversBuilder.scanTypeName(Class)] with root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying what you have to do, use `javers.packagesToScan` property in your `application.yml` as described here https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/#javers-configuration-properties

Comment: setting javers.packagesToScan="mypackage" but still getting type-name-not found
any idea how to fix it?
or how to register package to scan with javers in spring boot ??

Comment: Try to find the reason of your issue, whats going on when `withPackagesToScan()` is executed? Is this method called? What's logged? See the source here, it's easy to understand and debug https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/d5ac085c94b5459d464a14ab3e489f31e3c7c110/javers-core/src/main/java/org/javers/core/JaversBuilder.java#L284

Answer (score 0):

- By default javers store complete package path(com.app.model.Person)
  as model name for which we are storing audits trails.Which might
  change during code refactoring. So while fetching audits logs we get
  error **TYPE_NAME_NOT_FOUND** because of old path still persist in
  javers tables.
- To avoid this we can use 2 strategies:
- use @Typescan("Person") annotation with model class and set
  javers.packagesToScan=com.app.model,com.app.doc.model in spring
  properties file
- Or run migration in all jv_* tables that will replace old path to new
  path